# Extract Last Data Tag from Last XML element using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which I have used xpath to extract the last Element.

So at the moment this line of code below:

```
    //Get The file from directory
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("docs/03-24-2014.xml");

    //Get last Element
    $last = $xml->xpath("/DocumentElement/Datas[last()]");
```

## Output

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (6) { ["Name"]=> string(12) "COM3-Screen1" ["AdjustMode"]=> string(10) "AutoAdjust" ["Time"]=> string(19) "03-24-2014 11:59:27" ["ScreenBrightnessValues_x0028_0-255_x0029_"]=> string(1) "2" ["AmbientBrightness_x0028_lux_x0029_"]=> string(1) "0" ["BrightnessPercentage"]=> string(2) "0%" } }
```

## Goal

What am trying to achieve is extract the last data tag called "BrightnessPercentage and store it in a string"

I tried `echo $last->BrightnessPercentage .;` but it didnt work!

Any help you be kindly appreciated

Comment: `echo $last[0]->BrightnessPercentage ;`

Comment: Namaste.. so it worked hun !!

Answer (score 1):

To get that attribute directly from `xpath` as string, do:

```
$brightness = (string)$xml->xpath("/DocumentElement/Datas[last()]/@BrightnessPercentage")[0];
```

requires PHP >= 5.4. If you are on a lower version, do:

```
$brightness = $xml->xpath("/DocumentElement/Datas[last()]/@BrightnessPercentage");
$brightness = (string)$brightness[0];
```